# Why can't I get the values into a dropdrownlist in Power App from SharePoint list

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list **"Möbler"**

[image]

Rubrik is a Freetext, and kategori is a choise list **(Stol,Bord)**

Why can't I make Kategori to a dropdownlist? I can't find it in the list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Choices(SPListName.ColumnName)
```

Comment: AMAZING, tryed to show records in gallery that matches the dropdown values to the sharepointlist... Filter(Möbler;Color = DropdownColor.Selected.Value)   ERROR incompatible types for comparison. the following types cannot be compared to record and text